# Symfony2: Display Bootstrap Switch Button and get selected values in controller

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, formbuilder

I want to Implement the following field in symfony2. It has 2 Radio Buttons, and they are styled like Switch using some bootstrap styling.

[Example here](http://www.bootply.com/K3nDDRQGRd)

above html and bootstrap, snippet displays desired output

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="option1"> On
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="option2" checked=""> Off
   </label>
</div>
```

which outputs

[image: preview of this]

for this example to work it requires  tag inside  tag.
but **symfony form builder is rendering**

```html
<radio>..</radio>
<label></label>
```

how can I render `<radio>` tag inside `<label>` using symfony form builder?

**In symfony** for checkbox we use this code ,  but it displays normal radio group,

```
->add('check', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    0 => 'On',
                    1 => 'Off'
                ),
                    'expanded'  => true,
                    'multiple'  => false,
                'data' => 1
            ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

And look at this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

Comment: you mean like line 48 in second link

Comment: Yes, you have to add their styles between 45-52

Comment: how can I add `'class="some_class"` inside child then ?

Comment: I tried that. this will apply style to **div containing child radio type and its label** I want to style child ..

Comment: Add a custom block widget in file and use it:
`{{- your_custom_block_widget(child) -}}`
instead of
`{{- form_widget(child) -}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65694/discussion-between-straw-hat-and-pawel-kolanowski).

Answer (score 0):

in ProjectType.php

```
  $builder->add('progress', 'choice', array('label'=>'State of the project',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'choices' => array(
                '1'=>'Draft',
                '2'=>'Advanced',
                '3'=>'Final step',
            )));
```

twig:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.progress) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    {% for key,choice in form.progress.vars.choices %}
                    <label class="btn btn-default {% if choice.value == form.progress.vars.value %}active{% endif %}">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{ form.progress.vars.id }}_{{ key }}" {% if choice.value == form.progress.vars.value %}checked{% endif %}
                               autocomplete="off" name="{{ form.progress.vars.full_name }}" value="{{ choice.value }}">
                        {{ choice.label }}
                    </label>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
```